# Why I am capturing subprocess output through stderr and not stdout?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am running PSExec tool through subprocess. If psexec (not the tool on the remote computer) fails to initiate, I need to break. Hence, I am capturing all the command prompt output in a file and parsing it:

```
logfile = file('Ocd_Log.txt','w')

try:

  process = subprocess.Popen(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\PSTools\PsExec.exe" -s -i 1 -d -u administrator -p pwd \\10.200.20.20 cmd.exe /k "C:\Osprey_OCD_Daemon_xtensa_9.lnk"', stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

  for line in process.stderr:
    print ' '
    sys.stderr.write(line)
    logfile.write(line)
   process.wait()
```

The above code works good and captures all the command line to the logfile. But I am unable to understand why I need to capture the output through process.stderr and not process.stdout. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program choose stdout or stderr (in your case PsExec.exe, u cant fix it). In common, stderr is used for debug data, it is exactly what logfile is!

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this. This is just the truth. `PsExec.exe` writes to `stderr` and therefore the data is available on `stderr` only.

Comment: What I got is it depends on the process whether it will give output on stdout or stderr. For Psexec it is stderr and not stdout.